# connect-history-api-fallback vs app.get('*', [callback])

Tags: javascript, express, single-page-application

When solving SPA 404 problem, nomally use `connect-history-api-fallback`.
but I don't know advantages of using that middleware.

```js
app.use('/api',apiRouter);
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'~~'))
})
```

It has same result. Right?

What is the advantage of using `connect-history-api-fallback`?

I don't know the difference. And what kind of problems it causes.